# Select-box with textinput

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following Select-Box:

```
<select class="form-control" id="a-tenantID2">
    <option value="">Only Tenant</option>
        <optgroup label="editor">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="test1">test1</option>
        </optgroup>
    </option>
</select>
```

No I want to achieve, that If the first option is selected (the one without name), there appears an text-input field, so someone can write his own value into it.

How is that possible?

Comment: bind a change event check the value of none if it is then show the text input.

Comment: You would need a function in javascript to check if <option value="none"> was selected. If <option value="none"> was selected your function must then display a text input and after that handle the input in whichever way you need to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an input box

```
<input class="form-input" name="value" type="text" style="display:none">
```

Add an on-change event 
http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on("change", ".form-control", function(){
    if ($(this).val()=="none")
        $(".form-input").show();
    else 
        $(".form-input").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something with `.change()` event in conjunction with `.toggle()`:

```
$('.form-control').change(function(){
    $('#idofInput').toggle(this.value === "none");
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

If using vanilla Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('a-tenantID2').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  document.getElementById(this.id + '_input').classList[this.value !== 'none' ? 'add' : 'remove']('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="a-tenantID2">
  <option value="">Only Tenant</option>
  <optgroup label="editor">
    <option value="none"></option>
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
<input type="text" id="a-tenantID2_input" class="hidden" />
```